# how to convert a list of 2D Points in Python to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

```
2dpointList = [ Point(2020-01-31 23:00:00, 33.0), Point(2020-02-01 00:00:00, 33.0)]
```

how can I convert it to a dataframe where the indexes are the datatime

Comment: 2dpointList` results in a syntax error. What exactly is `Point()`? A minimal working example would help a lot.

Comment: This has 2D points https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/spatial.html . You're using datetimes

Comment: 2dpointList gives a syntax error please elaborate or write it in a proper way

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a Python dictionary:

```
point_list_2d = {
  "2020-01-31 23:00:00": 33.0,
  "2020-02-01 00:00:00": 33.0
}
```

That should do the job.

Comment: This isn't a dataframe.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for pointing it out! I'll wait to see if the answer is of any use to the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

first create a dictionary out of your list of points like

```
x={ i[0]:i[1] for i in 2dpointList}
```

then create a series using

```
pd.Series(x)
```